# short to int cast, weird behaviour

Tags: java, casting, bytebuffer

I currently read from a ByteBuffer a short value and apply it to an int.

```
byte[] data = new byte{0x90, 0xAF};
ByteBuffer b = ByteBuffer.wrap(data);
int value = b.getShort();
```

but the `value` contains now `0xFFFF90AF` and not `0x90AF`. 
My solution is to bitmask the value by `0xFFFF`: `int value = b.getShort() & 0xFFFF;`

I thought that a upcast is always possible, because `short` is smaller than `int`. Can someone explain why it behaves like this?

Comment: A side comment: `short` to `int` is not an *upcast* since `int` is not a supertype of `short`. It's called a *widening conversion*.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`short` is signed, and that is preserved when casting to `int`. 0x90AF is a negative `short`, so the result is negative `int`. Your solution of masking it is correct.

Answer (score 2):

`short` is a signed quantity, but you are in luck: there is also `char`, which is the only *unsigned* primitive type in Java, and is the same size as `short`. Try to use

```
int value = b.getChar();
```

It is an often neglected fact that `char` is a full-blown numeric type in Java; it is only its string representation which betrays its special status.